# Unable to mount Audio Disk: Message recipient disconnected from messages bus without replying

Tags: mount, cd, cd-ripping, audio-player

When I insert audio CD I get the following message:

> Unable to mount Audio Disk Message recipient disconnected from
>   messages bus without replying

When I start Sound Juicer the following message appears:

> Could not read the CD Sound Juicer could not read the track listing on
>   this CD. Reason: Cannot access CD: The specified location is not
>   mounted

For your info:

- VLC can play the CD by selecting "Audio CD" and /dev/sr0, but the playback stops a few times and after a while computer hangs and hard reset is required (even ctrl-alt-F1 does not work)
- the CD is not visible in Rhythmbox
- other music CDs can be played and extracted with Sound Juicer on this machine without any problem
- the CD I insert plays music in car CD drive without any problem
- also Mac can play this CD and import it into iTunes, so I am sure physical media is ok

***However*** when I insert various CDs into this machine I am getting following errors on console 1 (Shift-Alt-1):

[image: Photo of Console-1 errors]

I have gvfs-backends installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep gvfs

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gvfs/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gvfs-backends/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gvfs-bin/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gvfs-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 all [installed]
gvfs-daemons/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gvfs-fuse/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gvfs-libs/xenial-updates,now 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
```

I also did the cdrom group correction as suggested by the answer below:

```
$ ls -l /dev/cdrom /dev/sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 lip  9 21:53 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 lip  9 21:53 /dev/sr0
$ cat /etc/group | grep cdr
cdrom:x:24:someadmin
$ sudo adduser myuser cdrom
[sudo] password for myuser: 
Adding user `myuser' to group `cdrom' ...
Adding user myuser to group cdrom
Done.
$ cat /etc/group | grep cdr
cdrom:x:24:someadmin,myuser
...reboot...
$ id
uid=1001(myuser) gid=1001(myuser) groups=1001(myuser),24(cdrom),129(vboxusers),999(docker),1002(xcryptusers)
```

and the problem unfortunately persists.

Comment: Are you able to play the disc using `vlc`?

If it's not installed, install it by `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: @AmithKK VLC can play the CD by selecting "Audio CD" and /dev/sr0, but the playback stops a few times and after a while computer hangs and hard reset is required (even ctrl-alt-F1 does not work)

Comment: Is this limited to one CD or the same for _every_ audio CD? Does the same CD work on other systems?

Comment: @AmithKK  other music CDs can be played and extracted with Sound Juicer on this machine without any problem, the CD I insert plays music in car CD drive without any problem. Also Mac can play this CD and import it into iTunes, so I am sure physical media is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at `/dev/cdrom`, we see (on MY system, YMMV):

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /dev/cdrom 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul  9 10:06 /dev/cdrom -> sr0 
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /dev/cdrom /dev/sr0 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Jul  9 10:06 /dev/cdrom -> sr0 
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Jul  9 10:06 /dev/sr0 
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

that `/dev/cdrom` is a soft link to `/dev/sr0`, and that `/dev/sr0` is owned by `root:cdrom`. `/dev/sr0` is a `b`lock device, and allows `rw` (Read/Write) access to the owner (`root`) and members of the `cdrom` group. `/dev/sr0` denies access to users who are neither `root` nor in the `cdrom` group.

Use `id` to see if you are in the `cdrom` group. If not, read `man adduser`, and do:

```
sudo adduser $USER cdrom
```

Then, the next time you login, all of your processes will have `cdrom` group membership, and `rw` access to `/dev/cdrom -> /dev/sr0`.

Comment: Did it. Unfortunately the problem persists. @waltinator

Comment: Did what? Which of my several steps did you follow? What does `id` show you?

Comment: I have added output to the question above @waltinator